# Quelles sont des expressions équivalentes de « brasser la cage » ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, québec

Au Québec on a l'expression « brasser la cage » ou « ...la cabane » signifiant « Déranger, perturber, faire sortir de sa torpeur ou de son confort, notamment pour faire faire une prise de conscience ou donner lieu à un changement de comportement » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brasser_la_cage), voir aussi Blais, S. (2009). [*C’est à toi à brasser.*](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/qf/2009-n155-qf1093575/1798ac.pdf) Québec français, (155), 103–105).

Quelles sont des expressions équivalentes employées ailleurs dans la
francophonie ?

Comment: C'est probablement un calque de l'idiome anglais [rattle someone's cage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rattle_someone%27s_cage#:~:text=(informal)%20To%20demand%20attention%20from,anger%20or%20to%20annoy%20someone.), même si le sens est un peu différent.

Answer (score 4):

Je proposerais *donner un coup de pied dans la fourmilière* ou bien aussi *mettre les pieds dans le plat*. Peut-être aussi, suivant le contexte, et si on veut l'utiliser dans ce sens: *faire sauter la boutique*.

Il y aussi *mettre le feu aux poudres*, *remuer le couteau dans la plaie*, *venir comme un chien dans un jeu de quilles*, et *se comporter comme un éléphant dans un magasin de porcelaine*, avec différentes nuances qui s'éloignent quand même un peu de ce que l'on cherche, mais il n'est pas inconcevable d'utiliser ces expressions pour le sens recherché "Déranger, perturber, faire sortir de sa torpeur ou de son confort, notamment pour faire faire une prise de conscience ou donner lieu à un changement de comportement".

Comment: Assez formel, "réveiller les consciences" pourrait aussi convenir.

Comment: *un pavé dans la mare* aussi

Answer (score 3):

Secouer les puces à quelqu’un.

> fam. *Secouer les puces à qqn*, le réprimander fortement; l'inciter vivement à l'action.
> ⇒  fam. brasser la cage (à qqn).

Source : [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/puce#e07e584c647a57ac)

Comment: L'expression québécoise est à propos de faire prendre conscience à quelqu'un le faire sortir de sa zone de confort pas de l'engueuler il me semble.

Answer (score 0):

À part le "piétiner la fourmilière" de Frank, les autres réponses suggèrent plus "ruiner, provoquer des dégâts par violence gratuite" que "déclencher un changement brutal"; "secouer les puces" m'évoque un châtiment corporel.

J'utilise couramment "secouer le cocotier" que comprennent mes collègues et qui, dans la définition du [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/secouer_le_cocotier), me paraît l'équivalent exact de "brasser la cage".

Toutefois, Larousse ne reconnaît [qu'une acception très spécialisée](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cocotier/16868) de cette expression. Pendant la crise financière de 2008, la xyloglosse RH en a lancé un équivalent, "affiner la pyramide des âges", en remplacement de "dégraisser le mammouth".

Answer (score -1):

On dirait un cas de ***les casser***, une circonlocution ou périphrase plus polie que *casser les couilles.* Ce n'est pas très élégant mais ça se dit pour déranger quelqu'un, *faire sortir de son cage*, une provocation dans le sens original.

*Briser* n'est pas loin de l'étymologie.  Briser la glace par exemple, les jeux de brise-glace sont peut-être les plus préférés du monde (ou pas).

Il y a aussi :

> **[Briser](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=133733220;) ses chaînes**, ses fers, son joug. S'affranchir d'une domination
> tyrannique

Et [**fouler aux pieds**](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/fouler#ba16d6fd21beb45d) :

> (expression) Fouler aux pieds : piétiner, marcher avec violence sur
> qqn, qqch.; fig. mépriser, dédaigner, bafouer.

Cette définition-ci de brasser la cabane me rappelle plusieurs possibilités de *casser* et *briser*:

[Brasser la cabane](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/lexies?lt=brasser),

> Q/Cfam.fig.expression Exercer sur une personne ou un milieu, par son
> discours ou ses actions, une forte pression ayant comme but ou comme
> effet de provoquer du changement.

Comment: Les expressions choisies sont à mon avis trop proches de provoquer/faire fâcher/ faire sortir de ses gonds, mais sans l'objectif d'amener un changement; brasser une cage ce n'est pas la casser. Comparer avec _brasser_ tout court dans l'article, d'une certaine manière plus proche des choix qu'on a fait.

Comment: L'expression québécoise est à propos de faire prendre conscience à quelqu'un le faire sortir de sa zone de confort pas d'emmerder les gens.